# Shopware 6 Flow Builder and an other Email Template for "Customer account registered"

Tags: shopware, shopware6

i have a question: when i want to send a diffent email template in the case of a customer account registration in a specific sales channel (based on a condition from the rule builder), i switch to "**Settings**", "**Shop**", "**Flow Builder**", edit the flow with the name "**Customer account registered**", click on the tab "**Flow**" and edit the "**send email**" action and change the Email template to an other (or new) Email template.

When i do this, it doesn't work, the email will not be sended. But when i duplicated the Email Template with the type "**Customer registration**" and use this Email template instead of an other Email template (or a new one), it works. Why is this so? So in this case, does it always have to be an Email template of the type "**Customer registration**"? Or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

This is very likely due to a [twig syntax](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html) error in your template. For example this could happen if you used variables that can't be resolved from the data available to the template. You'll have to double check for missing brackets and such. Also with the variables try to use those from the default template. Also when you edit an email template you should see in the sidebar to the right an icon with the symbol `</>`. When you click on that it will show you the variables that were available the last time that template was send.

Comment: Did you check it or is this just a guess on your part? 

Before I created the question, I assigned a different email template and completely removed its variables in both fields (Plain Text and HTML) so that only text was left - the problem still exists. So your tip doesn't help and cannot explain the behavior.

Comment: Process of elimination. You wrote it works with the original mail template. The only difference in mail templates is their content. The only reason the content of a mail template could cause a mail not going out is when there is an exception being caught due to syntax errors. This is by far the most common cause, especially if one template works and another doesn't it's pretty much always down to syntax errors.

Comment: However, this cannot be the reason if the only content for the two fields of the other email template is "this is example content".

Comment: There are multiple content related fields: `contentPlain`, `contentHtml`, `subject`, `senderName` are the fields that are being rendered and need to be twig syntax compliant. If you can dump the corresponding rows from `mail_template` and `mail_template_translation` and put them in your original question.

Comment: I recommend to check the logs (Settings->System ->Logs), for me I got error logs there when the email was not sent correctly